# Flutter OverflowBox is behind the next widget in a column

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, overflow, flutter-web

I'm working on a Flutter project and I am trying to use the [`OverflowBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) widget.

I have a list of widgets in a `Column`, one of them, in the middle is supposed to overflow the others based on some events by the user.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

The red `Container` needs to display the green `Container` that overflows it at the top and the bottom.
But as you can see on the image, the green `Container` is only visible above the previous `Container` (the blue one) but not on the next one (the black `Container`). It looks like it is behind.

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(
            child: OverflowBox(
              maxHeight: 150,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 150,
                width: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I get my green `Container` to be above the black one too ?

---

EDIT: For functionality purposes, I need the green `Container` to be a child/be created by the red `Container` (and not by the list where I could use a `Stack` widget). I need the logic to be inside the red and green ones.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, I didn't managed to solve this @BradenBagby :/

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: [@Harshawardhan Upasani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6313288/harshawardhan-upasani) no still no solution on my side

Answer (score 0):

It still uses Stack, but Green Container is still part of Red Container.

And it might be difficult to calculate margin if Container has dynamic height.

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: OverflowBox(
                maxHeight: 150,
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 50,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit my needs. I'm following the flutter principle, constraints go down and sizes go up. The list cannot know what are the sizes of each `Containers` to place them in a `Stack` (This is a simplified code).

Comment: How about this ? https://imgur.com/a/f5hyCbv

Answer (score 0):

Use of overlay, maybe solve your problem.

```
OverlayState? overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code snipped and failed to getting the design that you particularly wishing to achieve.

I have anther way to get such type of design. Which ia using `Stacl()` widget

Here is an complete example code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.black,
            )
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
          
          // to set a specific position of your widget use Positioned inside a Stack() widget
          
          /*
          bottom: 50,
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
          left: 100,
          right: 100,
          */
          child: OverflowBox(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code snippet]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the effort, however I need the green widget to be controlled/a child of the red one because it will be part of the functionality (the blue and dark widgets are here as example on how it will be including in a screen) :/